# scikit-learn learning_curve function throws a ValueError when fed a SVM Classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import learning_curve

car_data = pd.read_csv('car.csv')
car_data['car_rating'] = car_data.car_rating.apply(lambda x: 'acc' if x != 'unacc' else 'unacc')
car_data = pd.get_dummies(car_data, columns=['buying_price', 'maintenance', 'num_doors', 'persons', 'luggage_boot', 'safety'])

y = car_data.car_rating
X = car_data.drop(['car_rating'], axis=1)

clf = SVC(kernel='poly', degree=3, C=1000)
plot_learning_curve(estimator=clf, title="Test", X=X, y=y, cv=10)
```

Which returns the error

```
ValueError: The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1
```

Which makes no sense to me as the "car_rating" column absolutely has two classes. Doing a value count returns:

```
unacc    1210
acc       518
```

so there are two classes, one smaller than the other, but more than enough that a stratified k fold should be able to keep both in all the cuts. So what is causing the error?

The data set I'm using can be found [here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Car+Evaluation). I did change the column names and fold the 'good' and 'vgood' classes into 'acc' but other than that the data is unchanged

edit: here is the code of plot_learning_curve:

```
def plot_learning_curve(estimator, title, X, y, ylim=None, cv=None,
                        n_jobs=1, train_sizes=np.linspace(.1, 1.0, 10)):
    """
    Generate a simple plot of the test and training learning curve.

    Parameters
    ----------
    estimator : object type that implements the "fit" and "predict" methods
        An object of that type which is cloned for each validation.

    title : string
        Title for the chart.

    X : array-like, shape (n_samples, n_features)
        Training vector, where n_samples is the number of samples and
        n_features is the number of features.

    y : array-like, shape (n_samples) or (n_samples, n_features), optional
        Target relative to X for classification or regression;
        None for unsupervised learning.

    ylim : tuple, shape (ymin, ymax), optional
        Defines minimum and maximum yvalues plotted.

    cv : int, cross-validation generator or an iterable, optional
        Determines the cross-validation splitting strategy.
        Possible inputs for cv are:
          - None, to use the default 3-fold cross-validation,
          - integer, to specify the number of folds.
          - An object to be used as a cross-validation generator.
          - An iterable yielding tfdrain/test splits.

        For integer/None inputs, if ``y`` is binary or multiclass,
        :class:`StratifiedKFold` used. If the estimator is not a classifier
        or if ``y`` is neither binary nor multiclass, :class:`KFold` is used.

        Refer :ref:`User Guide <cross_validation>` for the various
        cross-validators that can be used here.

    n_jobs : integer, optional
        Number of jobs to run in parallel (default 1).

    taken from: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_learning_curve.html
    """
    plt.figure()
    plt.title(title)
    if ylim is not None:
        plt.ylim(*ylim)
    plt.xlabel("Training examples")
    plt.ylabel("Score")
    train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(
        estimator, X, y, cv=cv, n_jobs=n_jobs, train_sizes=train_sizes)
    train_scores_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
    train_scores_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)
    test_scores_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
    test_scores_std = np.std(test_scores, axis=1)
    plt.grid()

    plt.fill_between(train_sizes, train_scores_mean - train_scores_std,
                     train_scores_mean + train_scores_std, alpha=0.1,
                     color="r")
    plt.fill_between(train_sizes, test_scores_mean - test_scores_std,
                     test_scores_mean + test_scores_std, alpha=0.1, color="g")
    plt.plot(train_sizes, train_scores_mean, 'o-', color="r",
             label="Training score")
    plt.plot(train_sizes, test_scores_mean, 'o-', color="g",
             label="Cross-validation score")

    plt.legend(loc="best")
    return plt
```

here is the full stack trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-04113e3ff056> in <module>()
      1 # the built in learning curve
      2 clf = SVC(kernel='poly', degree=3, C=1000)
----> 3 plot_learning_curve(estimator=clf, title="Test", X=X, y=y, cv=10)

<ipython-input-9-022f43e40037> in plot_learning_curve(estimator, title, X, y, ylim, cv, n_jobs, train_sizes)
     50     plt.ylabel("Score")
     51     train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(
---> 52         estimator, X, y, cv=cv, n_jobs=n_jobs, train_sizes=train_sizes)
     53     train_scores_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
     54     train_scores_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in learning_curve(estimator, X, y, groups, train_sizes, cv, scoring, exploit_incremental_learning, n_jobs, pre_dispatch, verbose, shuffle, random_state)
   1126             clone(estimator), X, y, scorer, train, test,
   1127             verbose, parameters=None, fit_params=None, return_train_score=True)
-> 1128             for train, test in train_test_proportions)
   1129         out = np.array(out)
   1130         n_cv_folds = out.shape[0] // n_unique_ticks

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    777             # was dispatched. In particular this covers the edge
    778             # case of Parallel used with an exhausted iterator.
--> 779             while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
    780                 self._iterating = True
    781             else:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    623                 return False
    624             else:
--> 625                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    626                 return True
    627 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    586         dispatch_timestamp = time.time()
    587         cb = BatchCompletionCallBack(dispatch_timestamp, len(batch), self)
--> 588         job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    589         self._jobs.append(job)
    590 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    109     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    110         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 111         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    112         if callback:
    113             callback(result)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    330         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    331         # arguments in memory
--> 332         self.results = batch()
    333 
    334     def get(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters, return_n_test_samples, return_times, error_score)
    456             estimator.fit(X_train, **fit_params)
    457         else:
--> 458             estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
    459 
    460     except Exception as e:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    148 
    149         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, dtype=np.float64, order='C', accept_sparse='csr')
--> 150         y = self._validate_targets(y)
    151 
    152         sample_weight = np.asarray([]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py in _validate_targets(self, y)
    504             raise ValueError(
    505                 "The number of classes has to be greater than one; got %d"
--> 506                 % len(cls))
    507 
    508         self.classes_ = cls

ValueError: The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1
```

Comment: Its not the issue of your data. Its most probably due to the `cv`. Show the code of `plot_learning_curve` and full stack trace of error.

Comment: Alright, I've added the code and the full stack trace

Comment: Ok I am sorry. This error seems to be related to `train_sizes` param, not `cv`. I am currently debugging on your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the problem is due to `train_sizes`.

Initially the value is:

```
train_sizes=np.linspace(.1, 1.0, 10)
```

which is [used to find a train_sizes_abs](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f0ab589f/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L1101) attribute (which just converts the float fraction of the training set to actual numbers:

```
...
n_max_training_samples = len(cv_iter[0][0])
train_sizes_abs = _translate_train_sizes(train_sizes, n_max_training_samples)
...
...
```

This is then used to actually select [the incremental training data](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f0ab589f/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L1120) for each fold:

```
...
else:
    train_test_proportions = []
    for train, test in cv_iter:
        for n_train_samples in train_sizes_abs:
            train_test_proportions.append((train[:n_train_samples], test))
...
...
```

This leads to a problem that when the data is selected for the first training (the first values in `train_test_proportions`), it just by chance contains only a single class in it. There is little we can do about it.

But if we can shuffle the training data before this, then this problem will not happen (still rare chance is possible that the selected data after shuffling still contains single class, but its rare)

So we need to add the `shuffle` param in the `learning_curve` call:

```
train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(estimator, X, y, cv=cv,
                                                        n_jobs=n_jobs, 
                                                        train_sizes=train_sizes, 
                                                        shuffle=True)
```

After that the code will run successfully.